# Process: com.example.whatsappclone java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, nullpointerexception

i am getting this error

java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter it

i don't know which variable is null i have used everything

need help , i am a beginner in android development , pls don't judge me

**i know it's a simple mistake but unable to find it**

Following is the entire code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVT1T.png)

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.whatsappclone.Adapters.ChatAdapter
import com.example.whatsappclone.Models.MessageModel
import com.example.whatsappclone.databinding.ActivityChatDetailBinding
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class ChatDetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityChatDetailBinding//view binding
    private lateinit var mDbRef: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var messageList: ArrayList<MessageModel>
    private lateinit var chatAdapter: ChatAdapter
    private var senderRoom: String? = null
    private var receiverRoom: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        //view binding
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityChatDetailBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        //removing action bar
        supportActionBar?.hide()

        //getting instance of auth
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        //getting database reference
        mDbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

        messageList = ArrayList()

        val senderId = auth.currentUser?.uid//sender Id
        val receiverId = intent.getStringExtra("userId")//receiver Id

        senderRoom = senderId + receiverId
        receiverRoom = receiverId + senderId

        //getting intent extra
        val userName = intent.getStringExtra("userName")
        val profilePic = intent.getStringExtra("profilePic")

        //putting intent extra values in views
        binding.username.text = userName
        if (!profilePic.equals("")) {
            Picasso.get().load(profilePic).placeholder(R.drawable.defaultprofile)
                .into(binding.IVProfileImage)
        }

        //on click listener on back button
        binding.btnBack.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@ChatDetailActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            this.finish()
        }

        //chat recycler view adapter
        chatAdapter = ChatAdapter(messageList, this)
        binding.chatRecyclerView.adapter = chatAdapter
        binding.chatRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        mDbRef.child("chats")
            .child(senderRoom!!).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    messageList.clear()
                    for (postSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                        val model = postSnapshot.getValue(MessageModel::class.java)
                        messageList.add(model!!)
                    }
                    chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                }

            })

        //on click on send button
        binding.send.setOnClickListener {
//            Toast.makeText(this, "sid:- " + senderId.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
//            Toast.makeText(this, "rid:- " + receiverId.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val message = binding.etMessage.text.toString()
            val model = MessageModel(senderId!!, message)
//            Toast.makeText(this, "mess- ${messageList.size}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
//            Toast.makeText(this, "id- ${senderId}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            model.timeStamp = Date().time
            binding.etMessage.setText("")

            mDbRef.child("chats").child(senderRoom!!).push()
                .setValue(model).addOnSuccessListener {
                    mDbRef.child("chats").child(receiverRoom!!).push()
                        .setValue(model)
                }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The error will tell you a line number. Which line is the one with the error?

Comment: When it tells you that `it` is null, it usually means you have a Kotlin lambda that inferred/assumed a non-null type for its input but got a null value. Sometimes you can replace `{ do_stuff(it) }` with something like `{ foo: Foo? -> do_stuff(foo) }` to set the type to properly nullable. The error message will tell you a line number to point you to which lambda is causing the problem. You should also avoid using `!!` in most cases - the whole point of nullable parameters is to protect you from accidentally using them and `!!` bypasses that protection.

Comment: i have added the image in description its line 12

Comment: Been seeing a bunch of these errors posted on here lately, always lambdas passed to some Firebase call which apparently passes nulls but makes Kotlin believe it won't. Does ``addOnSuccessListener { it: TResult? ->`` work (at the end of your code there)? I'm not sure what the type is exactly, but explicitly making it nullable might help

Comment: yes you are right the it parameter in lambda is set non-null that's why it is throwing error, thanks for the help it is working fine now